# Fade text out on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with Bootstrap 3, and have made the below fade in `paragraf` text when a person is hovering over the picture.

It is not gonna look good if the head and subline is there, therefore I would like the head and sub-headline is fading out, when a person hover the image, so it is only the `paragraf` text there is shown.

I am not quite sure how to do that, or how to get started on it. Can somebody give me some advice on this?

A live demo can be [seen here](http://vouzalis.dk/hover-stack.html).

```css
body {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }

  .mk.row [class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
  
  .mk.row {
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
    background-color: #fff
  }
  
  .img-responsive {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  /* Position of buttons/text in a single grid element */
  
  .inner-wrapper {
    background: none;
  }
  
  .bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 6%;
  }
  .light-font {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

/* Hover for grid elements that contains text */
 .hovereffect {
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(170,170,170,0.4);
}

.hovereffect h2, .hovereffect img {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.hovereffect p.info {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  top:5%; /* (100% - 85%)/2 */
  left:5%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.hovereffect:hover p.info {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="mk row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <a href="#">
              <div class="hovereffect">
                  <img src="https://drwyjmricaxm7.cloudfront.net/repository/TigerTrailItinerary1RegionalToursIndia-58141245765254_crop_610_410.jpg" alt="Accesories" class="img-responsive"></img>
                  <div class="overlay">
                      <a href="#">
                          <p class="info">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer vel interdum tempus egestas sed, eros ea ullamcorper tellus ut vestibulum ante. Id posuere sem est arcu, dapibus est. Neque ornare magna nunc volutpat blandit lorem, lacus sagittis ligula volutpat ac nullam<br/><br/> Vulputate luctus ipsum velit eget amet aliquam. Ac nibh dictum fermentum sodales, tincidunt metus placerat erat. In donec vitae luctus lorem repudiandae fames, explicabo donec in a non molestie. Montes ac quis eget morbi, vel 
                          </p>
                      </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-left">
                      <h3 class="light-font">This headline need to fade out</h3>
                      <span class="light-font">This subheadline should fade out when hover</span>
                      <!--<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Læs mere</button>-->
                  </div>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy

I have made slight changes to the `css` part

Just as you added the `.hovereffect:hover .overlay` for`<div class='overlay' ../>` rule 

Add `.inner-wrapper.bottom-left h3` selector with `:hover`

```css
body {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }

  .mk.row [class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
  
  .mk.row {
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
    background-color: #fff
  }
  
  .img-responsive {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  /* Position of buttons/text in a single grid element */
  
  .inner-wrapper {
    background: none;
  }
  
  .bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 6%;
  }
  .light-font {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

/* Hover for grid elements that contains text */
 .hovereffect {
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(170,170,170,0.4);
}

.hovereffect h2, .hovereffect img {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.hovereffect p.info {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  top:5%; /* (100% - 85%)/2 */
  left:5%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.hovereffect:hover p.info {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.hovereffect:hover .inner-wrapper.bottom-left h3,.hovereffect:hover .inner-wrapper.bottom-left span{
   
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.hovereffect:hover .inner-wrapper.bottom-left h3,.hovereffect:hover .inner-wrapper.bottom-left span{
  opacity:0;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="mk row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <a href="#">
              <div class="hovereffect">
                  <img src="https://drwyjmricaxm7.cloudfront.net/repository/TigerTrailItinerary1RegionalToursIndia-58141245765254_crop_610_410.jpg" alt="Accesories" class="img-responsive"></img>
                  <div class="overlay">
                      <a href="#">
                          <p class="info">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer vel interdum tempus egestas sed, eros ea ullamcorper tellus ut vestibulum ante. Id posuere sem est arcu, dapibus est. Neque ornare magna nunc volutpat blandit lorem, lacus sagittis ligula volutpat ac nullam<br/><br/> Vulputate luctus ipsum velit eget amet aliquam. Ac nibh dictum fermentum sodales, tincidunt metus placerat erat. In donec vitae luctus lorem repudiandae fames, explicabo donec in a non molestie. Montes ac quis eget morbi, vel 
                          </p>
                      </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-left">
                      <h3 class="light-font">This headline need to fade out</h3>
                      <span class="light-font">This subheadline should fade out when hover</span>
                      <!--<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Læs mere</button>-->
                  </div>
              </div>
          </a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is working is I wanted :-) Is it possible to control how long time the fade of the text is, when you remove the mouse from the image?

Comment: You can control it by updating  `transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;`   where 0.4 is the amount of time our transition work(suppose you need 800ms to complete the transition you can place 0.8 or 800ms in the rule )

Comment: But then it will also affect the fade in. It was more if it was possible to separate the fade. Fx fade-in: 0.4s and fade-out: 0.9s.

Comment: You can check the documentation for transition css property [here] <https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions>

Comment: Fx fade-in:0.4s and fade-out:0.9s might not be possible(only with css) but you can do the reverse(fade-in:0.9s,fade-out:0.4s,with `transition-delay` property)

Comment: I can see the answer is getting -1. Is it a bad solution?

Comment: I guess answer got -1 because I did not put any explanation. now i have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Set the `transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;` to the class `h3 and subheading` and set the `opacity:0` onhover, by doing this, you will get the same effect when you remove the mouse from the image. please check the below working snippet, hope it helps :)

```css
body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.mk.row [class*="col-"] {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.mk.row {
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  background-color: #fff
}

.img-responsive {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Position of buttons/text in a single grid element */

.inner-wrapper {
  background: none;
}

.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 6%;
}

.light-font {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Hover for grid elements that contains text */

.hovereffect {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.4);
}

.hovereffect h2,
.hovereffect img {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.hovereffect p.info {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  top: 5%;
  /* (100% - 85%)/2 */
  left: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.hovereffect:hover p.info {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.inner-wrapper.bottom-left h3,
.inner-wrapper.bottom-left span {
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect:hover .inner-wrapper.bottom-left h3,
.hovereffect:hover .inner-wrapper.bottom-left span {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="mk row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="hovereffect">
          <img src="https://drwyjmricaxm7.cloudfront.net/repository/TigerTrailItinerary1RegionalToursIndia-58141245765254_crop_610_410.jpg" alt="Accesories" class="img-responsive" />
          <div class="overlay">
            <a href="#">
              <p class="info">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer vel interdum tempus egestas sed, eros ea ullamcorper tellus ut vestibulum ante.
                Id posuere sem est arcu, dapibus est. Neque ornare magna nunc volutpat blandit lorem, lacus sagittis ligula
                volutpat ac nullam
                <br/>
                <br/> Vulputate luctus ipsum velit eget amet aliquam. Ac nibh dictum fermentum sodales, tincidunt metus placerat
                erat. In donec vitae luctus lorem repudiandae fames, explicabo donec in a non molestie. Montes ac quis eget
                morbi, vel
              </p>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-left">
            <h3 class="light-font">This headline need to fade out</h3>
            <span class="light-font">This subheadline should fade out when hover</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```